# Pipe output from DIR into CERTUTIL

Tags: batch-file, pipe, certutil

In Win10, looking for way to pipe the output from a DIR command at the Command Prompt or in a Batch File to serve as input to the CERTUTIL command. IOW, I want to get the MD5 hash for all of the files matched by a DIR command.

The following command does produce a bare list of all the files in the **E:\Temp** folder:

```
C:\Users\RAS>dir "E:\Temp" /b
```

But when I pipe that as shown in the following command, I get an error message:

```
C:\Users\RAS>dir "E:\Temp" /b | CertUtil -hashfile %~f1 MD5
CertUtil: -hashfile command FAILED: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The answer by user1686 at [Windows Vista piping dir output into attrib command](https://superuser.com/questions/546538/windows-vista-piping-dir-output-into-attrib-command) indicates that some commands (like ATTRIB) don't take file names as input, but I don't think that's relevant here.

The answer by Cliff Armstrong at [get the hash of a string and eventually compare it to a hash](https://superuser.com/questions/1467955/get-the-hash-of-a-string-and-eventually-compare-it-to-a-hash) looks promising, but I don't see how to pass each fully qualified file name to CERTUTIL. Also, I have no experience with PowerShell and would like to get a solution using a Batch File, if possible.

Thank you,

DW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that `Dir` will not put his own output in the correct argument for using `CertUtil` and, `CertUtil` will not place `Dir` redirected input in the right place (correct position/argument order) to use it.

If you try to use the `for /f` loop with the `where` command, instead of `dir /b` (it does not result in the full file path), this will result in the full file path and you can use the output loop variable in `Certutil`:

- In command line:

```all-bat
for /f tokens^=* %i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe "E:\Temp:*.*"')do @%__APPDIR__%CertUtil.exe -hashfile "%~i" MD5

rem :: Output  :: 

MD5 hash of E:\Temp\Turn Off LCD.exe:
3657b64bfa767cd1ce1ea3709053ea3b
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\LngVar.exe:
fc82a6b8fa5c24f6cbcb0f0dcbf85a2e
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\cocolor.exe:
d9a3def8f569afda41fb6e067c5f3df3
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\aria2c.exe:
80f598187166a8f95d86985ba0244257
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\cmdFocus.exe:
f90f8672fa57ba4e8f0a05dec3ede654
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\where.exe:
7b6f5b80b4db4ca0c0472625bcd0c981
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\SaveColor.exe:
0b24aa776ca4601bb39e6e529e73e7a6
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\Windows-ISO-Downloader.exe:
11532e016f68ef22ca96fa03020de789
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\sudoku.exe:
a3a946be19763b72f8aab6387079207a
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
```

- The same in bat/cmd file:

```all-bat
@echo off  

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe "E:\Temp:*.*
')do %__APPDIR__%CertUtil.exe -hashfile "%%~i" MD5"

rem :: Output :: 
MD5 hash of E:\Temp\Turn Off LCD.exe:
3657b64bfa767cd1ce1ea3709053ea3b
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\LngVar.exe:
fc82a6b8fa5c24f6cbcb0f0dcbf85a2e
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\cocolor.exe:
d9a3def8f569afda41fb6e067c5f3df3
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\aria2c.exe:
80f598187166a8f95d86985ba0244257
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\cmdFocus.exe:
f90f8672fa57ba4e8f0a05dec3ede654
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\where.exe:
7b6f5b80b4db4ca0c0472625bcd0c981
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\SaveColor.exe:
0b24aa776ca4601bb39e6e529e73e7a6
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\Windows-ISO-Downloader.exe:
11532e016f68ef22ca96fa03020de789
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
MD5 hash of F:\sudoku.exe:
a3a946be19763b72f8aab6387079207a
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
```

---

If you only need the MD5 strings in output, add `|find/v ":"`:

- In command line:

```all-bat
@for /f tokens^=* %i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe "E:\Temp:*.*"')do @%__APPDIR__%CertUtil.exe -hashfile "%~i" MD5|find/v ":"

rem :: Output  :: 

3657b64bfa767cd1ce1ea3709053ea3b
fc82a6b8fa5c24f6cbcb0f0dcbf85a2e
d9a3def8f569afda41fb6e067c5f3df3
80f598187166a8f95d86985ba0244257
f90f8672fa57ba4e8f0a05dec3ede654
7b6f5b80b4db4ca0c0472625bcd0c981
0b24aa776ca4601bb39e6e529e73e7a6
11532e016f68ef22ca96fa03020de789
a3a946be19763b72f8aab6387079207a
```

- In bat/cmd file:

```all-bat
@echo off 

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe "E:\Temp:*.*"
')do %__APPDIR__%CertUtil.exe -hashfile "%%~i" MD5|find/v ":"

rem :: Output  :: 

3657b64bfa767cd1ce1ea3709053ea3b
fc82a6b8fa5c24f6cbcb0f0dcbf85a2e
d9a3def8f569afda41fb6e067c5f3df3
80f598187166a8f95d86985ba0244257
f90f8672fa57ba4e8f0a05dec3ede654
7b6f5b80b4db4ca0c0472625bcd0c981
0b24aa776ca4601bb39e6e529e73e7a6
11532e016f68ef22ca96fa03020de789
a3a946be19763b72f8aab6387079207a
```

---

You also can do it more simple and recursively using For / r, same used in like **[linked question:](https://superuser.com/questions/1467955/get-the-hash-of-a-string-and-eventually-compare-it-to-a-hash)**

- In command line:

```all-bat
@for /r E:\temp %i in (*)do @%__APPDIR__%CertUtil.exe -hashfile "%~i" MD5|find/v ":"
```

- In bat/cmd file:

```all-bat
@echo off 

for /r E:\temp %%i in (*)do %__APPDIR__%CertUtil.exe -hashfile "%%~i" MD5|find/v ":"
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Where](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**

  [√] **[Where (pswhere in PowerShell)](https://www.petri.com/using-get-fileitem)**

  [√] **[CertUtil](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html)**

  [√] **[More Tricks with CertUtil](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8521)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[CMD/Bat String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**

  [√] **[Base64 Encode or Decode (MacOS/Windows/Linux)](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2017/04/26/base64-encode-or-decode-on-the-command-line-without-installing-extra-tools-on-linux-windows-or-macos/)**

Answer (score 0):

You stated,

> I want to get the MD5 hash for all of the files matched [...]

I was also trying to match hashes and was also getting the error

> CertUtil: -hashfile command FAILED: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2
> ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

The solution I found was to download a hash checker app, which apparently did a good job. It extracted the hash from the document, compared it with the one I provided and found they matched.

I saw [a few such apps](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/search/hash%20checker) in the Microsoft App store. The one I got had several options for hash types, including SHA256 and MD5.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).